# Using Meteor.call inside a server router

Tags: meteor

```
Router.route('/sms/inbound', function () {
  if (something) {
    Meteor.call("addUser", {
      name: "hello",
      age: 20
    })
  }
}, {where: 'server'});
```

I want to do something like above. However, since `Meteor.call` is used on the client to make calls to server-side functions, it doesn't seem right to me. In collections you usually define methods like `addUser` inside `Meteor.methods` block. How am I supposed to call this function from the server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restructure your method where you also name the function of the method, then you have two entry points into whatever code it is you'd like to execute:

```
addUser = function() {
   ...
};

Meteor.methods({'addUser': addUser});

Router.route('/sms/inbound', function () {
  if (something) {
    addUser({
      name: "hello",
      age: 20
    });
  }
}, {where: 'server'});
```